# Parameter #1 is not set error

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I got an error with grails query. 
I had class User:

```
class User {
String username
String passwordHash

static hasMany = [roles: Role, permissions: String, clients: User, owners: User]
}
```

When i do query:

```
def addClient() {
    def principal = SecurityUtils.subject?.principal
    User currentUser = User.findByUsername(principal);
    if (request.method == 'GET') {
        User user = new User()
        [client: currentUser, clientCount: User.countByOwners(currentUser)]
    }
}
```

Grails say that:

Parameter "#1" is not set; SQL statement: select count(*) as y0_ from user this_ where this_.id=? [90012-164]

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `currentUser` is `null`.

BTW, I wonder, why you count by owners, but specify a user as the owners? According to your `hasMany` definition, `owners` is a collection.

Comment: Yes, your right, problem that owners is a collection. I solved problem whis way: User.withCriteria { owners { inList("id", [currentUser.id]) } }.size()